# Selecting values for multiple properties based on a string

Tags: c#, .net

I'm building an automated workflow system that will have to set 4 string values based on the name of the file being read. I have a functioning switch statement but as you'll see in the example I have a lot of shared values between different file names. I'm looking for a way to streamline this code since soon I'll have as many as 40 different file names to work with.

Each file must be assigned the following properties: AccountName, CampaignName, DocumentName, and DestinationName. The account and campaign are frequently shared between similar files, but the document are almost always unique. See below for an example.

```
case "Cow":
    accountName = "Farm Animals";
    campaignName = "Quadrupeds";
    documentName = "Milk Givers";
    destinationName = "Milking Line";
    break;
case "Chicken":
    accountName = "Farm Animals";
    campaignName = "Bipeds";
    documentName = "Egg Layers";
    destinationName = "Coupe";
    break;
case "Turkey":
    accountName = "Farm Animals";
    campaignName = "Bipeds";
    documentName = "Dinner";
    destinationName = "My Table";
    break;
case "Dog":
    accountName = "Farm Animals";
    campaignName = "Quadrupeds";
    documentName = "Best Friend";
    destinationName = "Front Porch";
    break;
case "Pig":
    accountName = "Farm Animals";
    campaignName = "Quadrupeds";
    documentName = "Bacon";
    destinationName = "My Plate";
    break;
```

I don't know if a Dictionary is what i'm looking for, or if I'd build a custom class that I could select the values by using LINQ, which is why I'm here.

I want to cut down on repetition of values to make it more manageable. Something like a micro relational database to hold the different values and what documents belong to them.

**My questions are: Is there a better way to approach this without a switch statement? And is there a better name for my question based on what I need?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so each parameter is a one-to-many relationship in relation to each animal. My solution would be to create dictionaries for each parameter, with a type of `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, like so:

```
var accountNames = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
    {
        {"Farm Animals", new List<string> {"Cow", "Chicken", "Turkey", "Dog", "Pig"}}
    };
```

Then you would use it in a fashion similar to this (this example uses anonymous types). You may want to make an extension method for the value retrieval to clean up the code and make it case insensitive.

```
foreach(var animal in animals)
{
    var item = new
        {
            AccountName = accountNames.First(x => x.Value.Contains(animal)).Key
        };
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. No parameters will need to be repeated, and each animal will only be used a maximum of 4 times.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary as  described below :-

```
    public  class ElementName
    {
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public string CampaignName { get; set; }
        public string DocumentName { get; set; }
        public string DestinationName { get; set; }
    }
        var animalNameDict = new Dictionary<string, ElementName>
            {
                {
                    "cow",
                    new ElementName
                        {
                            AccountName = "Farm Animals",
                            CampaignName = "Quadrupeds",
                            DocumentName = "Milk Givers",
                            DestinationName = "Milking line"
                        }
                }
            };
        ElementName elem = null;
        animalNameDict.TryGetValue("cow", out elem);

        var item = animalNameDict.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "cow");
```

or you can turn it to a list of class and use the linq extension ToLookup.

Comment: Great suggestion aside from the fact that it still requires as many references to the values I'm working with as my switch statement. A dictionary was definitely the way to go though.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no way to reduce the number of lines of code because there is no way to know what `accountName` or `campaignName` to pick without wiring something up somewhere.  You can setup a dictionary like TYY proposes, but it still requres four assignments for each file (type?).

Either way, I would suggest having at least the common strings, such as `"Farm Animals"` and `"Quadrupeds"`, defined as constants somewhere to reduce the chance of type-os and make it easier to change if needed.

Comment: I will definitely be placing the various names into a resource to create a one-stop spot for changing any values.

Comment: I'm still a few rep points away from being able to up vote, otherwise Jim would get another.  I thought about a list of files for each AccountName but couldn't of a good way to find the right one. Also, I didn't realize you could initialize a `List<T>` like that... fancy.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using reflection to use a factory to create the animals:

```
namespace mynamespace
{
    public class FarmAnimal
    {
        public string accountName = "Farm Animals";
    }
    public class Quadruped : FarmAnimal
    {
        public string campaignName = "Quadrupeds";
    }
    public class Dog : Quadruped
    {
        public string documentName = "Best Friend";
        public string destinationName = "Front Porch";

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0} : {1} : {2} : {3}", accountName, campaignName, documentName, destinationName);
        }
    }

    public class AnimalFactory
    {
        public static FarmAnimal create(string fileName)
        {
            try {
                ObjectHandle h = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "mynamespace." + fileName);
                return  (FarmAnimal)h.Unwrap();
            }
            catch (Exception) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FarmAnimal a = AnimalFactory.create("Dog");
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be to use the [Factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx) or [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern). This way you can delegate this code to another project and do whatever you want.